# Disabling usetex in matplotlib tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I'm trying to create a figure using Python (version 3.5.3) and Matplotlib (version 2.0.2). I would like one of the axes of the figure to be labeled with an equation rendered in Latex. To render the equation, I need to use the amsmath and amsfonts packages.

The only way I have managed to do this is by globally setting usetex=True for all text in matplotlib figures. However, that causes the tick labels to be rendered in Latex as well. Can I prevent this, and if so, how?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
preamble='\\usepackage{amsmath}\n\\usepackage{amsfonts}'

plt.rc('text',usetex=True)
plt.rc('text.latex',preamble=preamble)

fig,ax=plt.subplots()

all_lambda = np.linspace(-6,2,1000)
ax.plot(all_lambda,np.exp(-np.exp(all_lambda)))
ax.set_xlim([-6,2])
ax.set_ylim([-0.1,1.1])
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\log\lambda$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\mathbb{P}(m=0\lvert \lambda)$')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib graph]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use MathText instead of latex?

```
plt.rcParams["mathtext.fontset"] = "stixsans"
```

Complete example without latex:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["axes.labelsize"] = "large"
plt.rcParams["mathtext.fontset"] = "stixsans"


fig,ax=plt.subplots()

all_lambda = np.linspace(-6,2,1000)
ax.plot(all_lambda,np.exp(-np.exp(all_lambda)))
ax.set_xlim([-6,2])
ax.set_ylim([-0.1,1.1])
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\log\lambda$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\mathbb{P}(m=0\left| \lambda\right)$')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm planning to include this figure in a manuscript that I'm writing in Latex, so I prefer to have the formatting of the axes labels be the same as the text in the caption etc. But as a backup plan, I can try this

Comment: You may use "stix" instead of "stixsans". Apart, having this in a latex document, why would you not like your initial solution, which has all the same style? How exactly do you want your ticklabels to look like?